# Github clone and pull

Tags: git, github

I am new to `GitHub`. My friend and I plan to develop a simple project and we both plan to upload it in
[Github](https://github.com/yurkz/POS). He try to clone my project and he successfully clone it. But the problem upon committing the changes he made his github account generate a new [Repository](https://github.com/opt33mos/POS). Our plan is that we just want to use my repository. How can he/we achieve solve this problem?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On github you can add a collaborator. To do this, go to your repo > settings > manage access > invite a collaborator.

Your friend will receive an email inviting him to your repository. Once he accept your invitation, he will have collaborator access to your repository

Comment: once he accept it?. what should we do next?

Comment: @KiRa he can modify your repo. That's all

Comment: can he pull/commit changes to it?.

Comment: does he need to clone it again or  ?.

Comment: @KiRa i don't think so. If u want to be sure, clone it again

Comment: @KiRa can you please accept this answer as solved if it solved ypur problem?